# Top X% by group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have some machines and their sales in different groups e.g. machine age. My goal is to isolate the top 5% machines (for sales amount) within each group.

I managed to do this on the full dataframe using the following code

```
df['quantile'] = pd.qcut(df.Sales, 20, labels=range(20))
top = df[df['quantile']==0]
```

But I cannot seem to manage to do the same when using groupby. Essentially the assignment does not work. Any clue?

Comment: can you show us the code that fails and the error message/incorrect result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `groupby.transform` and `quantile`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(1,4,1000),
                   'Sales': np.random.uniform(0,1,1000)})
df['quantile'] = df.groupby('a').Sales.transform('quantile', 0.95)

#filter:
top = df[df.Sales.gt(df['quantile'])]
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Your answer is indeed correct. Thanks!